# Data Base Export Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Trying to clone my current wordpress site and put it on a second server to test new plugins and updating. Have been trying different methods of cloning and I keep running into a problem with the database.

I'm able to export the database from Server A in phpMyAdmin but when I go to restore it in on Server B it only gives me an empty database with the same name. All the tables and data are gone that I selected to export.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Heres how I set up the Export:
[Database Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtlEr.png)

Heres how I set up the Import:
[Database Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HAZR.png)

Comment: have you checked your export? Does it look like valid sql? Do you have permission to create tables?

Comment: Depending on the speed of your server and the size of your database, the import process can sometimes time out. Have you tried separating out the insert from the create tables into separate files? Run your create tables file first, then run separate files to populate each one. This has the added advantage of showing where the failure is occurring.

Comment: I just tried a few things and I think there is a problem with the Select All option in phpMyAdmin as opposed than Shift+Cicking the top and bottom tables to select all because it took a little longer to export and import this time around. The new problem is that its giving me a file size error after reaching 100%

Comment: It can be problem with max file size for upload

Comment: how can I compress it down to under 50mb, I'm on a Mac

Comment: @Giovatto - you don't compress it, you split it into multiple files as I suggested in my earlier comment. Make one sql file that contains just your schema creation, and then as many files as necessary containing insert statements to get each file below your server's size limit. You'll need to do more than one import.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend learning how to use [mysqldump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/) on the command line, which is almost certainly what phpMyAdmin is using under the hood to do your database export. If you're using `mysqldump`, you can transfer the dump file via SSH (or whatever) and you won't have to deal with max upload sizes or anything like that.

In general, it's good to be proficient with low-level tools so you aren't dependent on web GUIs to do stuff.

Of course, my comments are useless if you're on shared hosting without shell access, and for all I know you already know how to use `mysqldump`, and you're being forced to use phpMyAdmin against your will due to hosting environment constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://support.tigertech.net/mysql-duplicate

It says you need to click on the database name on the left side before exporting, for no apparent reason, or else you won't be able to import the exported file into a new database.

Also, you have to cut your input files into small pieces. The UI says less than 50MB. In my experience, 10 MB won't work. Don't know just how big a file can be, but something less than 10 MB.